# Calculating scores in a Spreadsheet via Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So, after some hours of research and going through [these references](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) I managed only to declare some variables and create a for loop without anything inside. I can't figure out what I need to put in there and I'm not even sure if all those variables are practical. Needless to say I have almost no experience with JavaScript. I'm only good at using spreadsheet function and spreadsheet design :/

Here's a link to the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G55twwouyvv8G24M89OYHsVBFrceipXdE9hIGgTS5-E/edit?usp=sharing
Feel free to create a copy and check the code in the script editor. I'll also add my code at the end of this post, of course.

**Now, what's the purpose of this spreadsheet?**

- It tracks how long players in an online game have participated in a venture.
- You can see in the sheet the two teams of players (Escort and Miners) with durations to determine how long they participated in a venture. The "Wage" column for the Escort-Team isn't relevant for my question here.
- Important for this sheet is, that the columns "NAME", "FROM" and "UNTIL" are being reset after each venture!
  That's what the yellow button is for.
- Beside the teams there is a "Scores"-table which shall contain an ongoing score for the players.
  Players get a score based on the duration they participated.
- Right now, in the "Score" column it only looks up the current duration, but if the reset button is being pressed the scores do also reset. Also, the lookup checks only for the Escort-Team, because I didn't bother at the time as it's not working for me like this anyway.

**What I want the score button to do!**

- If the button is pressed it should lookup the current duration for each player in both teams and add the value to the corresponding cells under "Scores". So this will track the all-time score for each player.
- The number of participants in each team can differ for each venture.
- Names in the score table can change, new ones might be added or names might be removed at any time.
  There won't ever be a thousand players, but the user should be free to add as many names as he/she wants.

Here's what I managed to come up with so far.
Most of this code is based on what I found in [this article](https://yagisanatode.com/2017/12/13/google-apps-script-iterating-through-ranges-in-sheets-the-right-and-wrong-way/). I thought this to be pretty accurate for how I want to search for the data in my spreadsheet, but I'm getting stuck at the calculation due to my lag of knowledge. Any kind of help would be appreciated, whether it be working code or just hints to what functions I'll need for this.

```
function scoreButton() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetTime = ss.getActivesheet();
  
  var rangeEscort = sheetTime.getRange(5, 1, sheetTime.getLastRow()-4, 4);  // range for first team of players
  var rangeMiner = sheetTime.getRange(5, 7, sheetTime.getLastRow()-4, 10);  // range for second team of players
  var rangeScore = sheetTime.getRange(5, 12, sheetTime.getLastRow()-4, 14); // range for the scores
  
  var searchRangeEscort = sheetTime.getRange(5, 5, sheetTime.getLastRow()-5+1, sheetTime.getLastColumn()-5+1);
  var searchRangeMiner = sheetTime.getRange(5, 7, sheetTime.getLastRow()-5+1, sheetTime.getLastColumn()-7+1);
  var searchRangeScore = sheetScore.getRange(5, 12, sheetTime.getLastRow()-5+1, sheetTime.getLastColumn()-12+1);
  
  var rangeValues = searchRangeEscort.getValues();
  for (i = 0; i < lastColumnEscort - 1; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < lastRowEscort - 1; j++){
     
    };
  };
};
```

*EDIT: Updated code.*

Comment: I suggest you to add a summary at the top of your question and make the title more specific.

Comment: `var rangeEscort = sheetTime.getDataRange("A5:D");` getDataRange() does accept any parameters try `sheetTime.getRange(5,1,sheetTme.getLastRow()-4,4)`  Using A1 Notations like A5:D often return nulls at the end of the data that require filtering.  Recommend not using them unless you can specify specific row with them.

Comment: `var searchRangeEscort = sheetTime.getRange(5, 5, lastRowEscort-1, lastColumnEscort-1);` should be written as follows: `sheetTime.getRange(startRow,startColumn,sheetTime.getLastRow()-startRow+1,sheetTime.getLastColumn()-startColumn+1)`  the last two parameters are number of rows and number of columns.

Comment: Which columns do you want to add in each range?

Comment: @Rubén I once got told to be more detailed when explaining problems and usually nobody complains about it, but I guess I added some unnecessary information. I edited the title at least, but I'm just not very good in giving summaries. It always feels like some important information will be missing. Sorry.

Comment: @Cooper I adjusted `var rangeEscort = ...` and `var searchRangeEscort = ...` as you pointed out. In the latter adjustment, should I declare startRow and startColumn as variables and should they be A1 notations (i.e. A5) or numbers or can they be just numbers as in `(5, 5, ...)`?

Comment: @Cooper I want to sum up D5:D and J5:J and add that to the total sum per player in M5:M.

Comment: Please your update your question to your current code

Comment: @Kuraiko " Any kind of help would be appreciated, whether it be working code or just hints to what functions I'll need for this." is not a question. See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1595451)

Comment: I see the values in column M are functions, if the script overwrites those cells, the formulas will be erased. Unless I'm missing something here.

Comment: @Jescanellas The formulas are in place right now as a workaround before the button works. They values in M get manually noted down before resetting the table right now.

Comment: @Rubén I see your point. The question is: How do I get the "Score Button" do what I want it to do as described below "What I want the score button to do!"?

Comment: @Cooper I updated my code and hopefully got it right? The for loop however now contains undeclared variables.